# ArrayList value show the column and related values in angular table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```js
var ArrayList = [{ Width: "3" }, { Width: "3.9" }, { Width: "4.4" },
{ Width: "2" }, { Width: "2.5" }, { Width: "1.625" }, { Width: null },
{ VoltageToleranceMax: null }, { ThresholdVoltage: null },
{ ThresholdVoltage: "2.55/2.88" }, { ThresholdVoltage: "1.2" },
{ ThresholdVoltage: "1.665" }, { ThresholdVoltage: "3.3" }]
```

Above array, list convert separate column

My Result:

```
Width | Threshold Voltage-Nom

3     |  2.55/2.88  
3.9   |  1.2     
4.4   |  1.665   
2     |  3.3 
2.5                   
1.625
```

convert the Array List to HTML table show in column and values

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the object follows the naming convention to avoid exception `Unexpected identifier`. As you can not take a key like `'Threshold Voltage'`. It should be `ThresholdVoltage`.

I have changed the array and follow the code to get your result.

```
var ArrayList = [ {Width: "3"}, {Width: "3.9"}, {Width: "4.4"}, 
   {Width: "2"}, {Width: "2.5"}, {Width: "1.625"}, {Width: null}, 
   {VoltageToleranceMax: null}, {ThresholdVoltage: null}, 
   {ThresholdVoltage: "2.55/2.88"}, {ThresholdVoltage: "1.2"}, 
   {ThresholdVoltage: "1.665"}, {ThresholdVoltage: "3.3"} ]

var widthNotFiltered  = ArrayList.map((res)=>{
  if(res.Width) {
    return res.Width;
  }
  return null;
});

var widthFiltered = widthNotFiltered.filter(function (el) {
   return el != null;
});

console.log(widthFiltered);
["3", "3.9", "4.4", "2", "2.5", "1.625"]
```

Likewise, get for Threshold Voltage-Nom

```
var thresholdNotFiltered  = ArrayList.map((res)=>{
  if(res.ThresholdVoltage) {
    return res.ThresholdVoltage;
  }
  return null;
});

var thresholdFiltered = thresholdNotFiltered.filter(function (el) {
   return el != null;
});

console.log(thresholdFiltered);
["2.55/2.88", "1.2", "1.665", "3.3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In ts :-

```
public arrayList = [{Width: "3"} {Width: "3.9"} {Width: "4.4"} {Width: "2"} {Width: "2.5"} {Width: "1.625"} {Width: null} {Voltage Tolerance-Max: null} {Threshold Voltage: null} {Threshold Voltage: "2.55/2.88"} {Threshold Voltage: "1.2"} {Threshold Voltage: "1.665"} {Threshold Voltage: "3.3"} ];

public modifiedData = {};

ngOnInit() {
   this.filterArray();
}

public filterArray() {
   this.arrayList.forEach((item) => {
      var itemArr = Object.entries(item)[0];
      if(!modifiedData[itemArr[0]]) {
         modifiedData[itemArry[0]] = [];
      }
      modifiedData[itemArry[0]].push(itemArry[1]);
   });
}
```

In HTML :-

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let data of modifiedData|keyvalue">{{data.key}}</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let data of modifiedData|keyvalue">
           <td>
                <table>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of data.value">
                       <td>{{item}}</td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
           </td>
      </ng-container>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: don't you think this will through an error 
`public arrayList = [{Width: "3"} {Width: "3.9"} {Width: "4.4"} {Width: "2"} {Width: "2.5"} {Width: "1.625"} {Width: null} {Voltage Tolerance-Max: null} {Threshold Voltage: null} {Threshold Voltage: "2.55/2.88"} {Threshold Voltage: "1.2"} {Threshold Voltage: "1.665"} {Threshold Voltage: "3.3"} ];`

Error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: actually you didn't see how i transformed your original array in my typescript code? please go through complete solution.